# MySQL: Group by one column but order by another

Tags: mysql

I have a table with restaurant names (venues)

| id | venue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Venue 1 |
| 2 | Venue 2 |
| 3 | Venue 3 |

And a table with special offers (specials)

| venue_id | offer | modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10% off | 2023-11-17 |
| 2 | 20% off | 2023-11-16 |
| 3 | 30% off | 2023-11-10 |
| 3 | 20% off | 2023-11-14 |
| 3 | 50% off | 2023-11-19 |

I am attempting to return the offers in reverse chronological order so the most recent appear first, but also group the venue names together

Any sort of join between these two tables ordered by Modified will return

```
SELECT v.venue, s.special, s.modified
FROM venues v, specials s
WHERE s.venue_id = v.id
ORDER BY modified DESC
```

| venue | offer | modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Venue 3 | 50% off | 2023-11-19 |
| Venue 1 | 10% off | 2023-11-17 |
| Venue 2 | 20% off | 2023-11-16 |
| Venue 3 | 20% off | 2023-11-14 |
| Venue 3 | 30% off | 2023-11-10 |

The problem is that I wish to also group the venues together so they can be output together.

Any attempt to GROUP BY venue will omit 2 of the records for Venue 3.

I want to order by Modified but group them together (which in my head defies logic) but ideally by grouping them based on the single most recent record for a venue (if that makes sense):

| Venue | Special | Modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Venue 3 | 50% off | 2023-11-19 |
| Venue 3 | 20% off | 2023-11-14 |
| Venue 3 | 30% off | 2023-11-10 |
| Venue 1 | 10% off | 2023-11-17 |
| Venue 2 | 20% off | 2023-11-16 |

Have attempted different types of subquery and joins but it's way to advanced for me.

Comment: "Any attempt to GROUP BY venue will omit 2 of the records for Venue 3": Of course it will. It will give you one row per distinct venue. That's what it does. That's what it's for. If that's not what you want, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a sub query to append the max modified to every venue row makes ordering simpler

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t
(venue varchar(10), offer varchar(10),  modified date);
insert into t values
('Venue 3', '50% off',  '2023-11-19'),
('Venue 1', '10% off',  '2023-11-17'),
('Venue 2', '20% off',  '2023-11-16'),
('Venue 2', '20% off',  '2023-11-19'),
('Venue 3', '20% off',  '2023-11-14'),
('Venue 3', '30% off',  '2023-11-10');


select *,(select max(modified) from t t1 where t1.venue = t.venue) maxmd
from t
order by maxmd desc ,venue,modified desc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/GsHy7TTX

note in the event of ties ,as in my sample data, you may need some other criterion for ordering.

Comment: Thanks! Based on the output of your fiddle this will work but I can't work out how to join the venue and the offers tables based on your syntax above.

Comment: A simple EXPLICIT join on venue should do.

Comment: Worked it out. Thanks so much, you nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you want:

```sql
SELECT v.venue, s.offer, s.modified
FROM specials s
JOIN venues v ON s.venue_id = v.id
ORDER BY
  (SELECT MAX(modified) FROM specials WHERE venue_id = v.id) DESC,
  venue_id,
  modified DESC;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT v.venue, s.offer, s.modified
FROM venues v
JOIN (
  SELECT venue_id, MAX(modified) m
  FROM specials
  GROUP BY venue_id
) AS maxm ON v.id = maxm.venue_id
JOIN specials s ON v.id = s.venue_id
ORDER BY maxm.m DESC, v.id, s.modified DESC;
```

Both output:

| venue | offer | modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Venue 3 | 50% off | 2023-11-19 |
| Venue 3 | 20% off | 2023-11-14 |
| Venue 3 | 30% off | 2023-11-10 |
| Venue 1 | 10% off | 2023-11-17 |
| Venue 2 | 20% off | 2023-11-16 |

The second query is likely to be faster with a larger dataset. Both queries will benefit from an index on `(venue_id, modified DESC)`.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M0Ghz_Xm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by multiple value then you can just do grouping query, for example :

```
SELECT v.venue, s.special, s.modified
FROM venues v INNER JOIN specials s ON s.venue_id = v.id
WHERE {additional filter}
GROUP BY v.venue, s.modified
```

can you just elaborate more on your question?

> I want to order by Modified but group them together (which in my head
> defies logic) but ideally by grouping them based on the single most
> recent record for a venue (if that makes sense):

It will actually better if based on dataset you provide you can give us your expected output because at this point your purpose is unclear

Edit: Solution if your version support CTE

```
SELECT s.*, v.*, MAX(s.modified) OVER (PARTITION BY s.venue_id ORDER BY s.modified DESC, s.venue_id) AS your_order FROM 
venues v INNER JOIN specials s ON v.id = s.venue_id
ORDER BY your_order DESC, v.venue, s.modified
```

[result should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odozF.png)

However you need to pay attention on what kind of ordering you gonna make when several venue used at the same date.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The desired output is the final table in the post - to group Venue 3 together first based on it having the most recent special

Comment: Oh, now it makes it clearer, you need to order it, not exactly group it. Please don't use term "grouping" here as most of user will think as actual grouping. To solve this you can simply use CTE

Answer (score 0):

You don't need group by, do you?

```
SELECT v.venue, s.special, s.modified
FROM venues v, specials s
WHERE s.venue_id = v.id
ORDER BY venue, modified DESC
```

(or Venue desc, modified desc if you also want them in reverse)

Comment: I think the op wants the order to be by the venue with the most recent first (then all the others for that venue) then the second most recent (then all the others for that venue) then the third etc.. and it's a coincidence(or a poor example) that venue 3 should happen to be the most recent.

Comment: Issue with ordering by venue is then they are in alphabetical order for venue. Goal is to output them chronologically, but also group them by name.

Comment: @SamW sorry I don't understand what you mean. I can't see the difference.